# Using Right() or Substr() in an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables :

```
Add_T
Add_ID   NUMBER(10,0)       
Add_GEOMETRY    SDO_GEOMETRY            
STRTN    VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)       
CITY      VARCHAR2(45 BYTE)         
STATE     VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)      
ZIPCODE   VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)     
HC_ID   NUMBER(10,0)        
P_ID    NUMBER(10,0)
```

Second Table    :

```
HC_T
HC_GEOMETRY    SDO_GEOMETRY 
HC_ID     NUMBER(10,0)
TYPE      VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)
FACY     NUMBER(10,0)
COORD_X   NUMBER(15,0)
COORD_Y     NUMBER(15,0)
```

I need to update the field `HC_ID` of `Add_T` Table and I use the following SQL statement:

```
 update add_t set hc_Id = ( SELECT HC_ID FROM HC_T
 WHERE ADD_T.P_ID = HC_T.FACY  AND
 HCO_T.TYPE='R' ) WHERE hc_ID IS NULL and
 subtr(strtn,-4,4) = "-LOC"
```

It doesn't work. Also, I used the `right()` function and also got incorrect results.

```
 update add_t set hc_Id = ( SELECT HC_ID FROM HC_T
 WHERE ADD_T.P_ID = HC_T.FACY  AND
 HCO_T.TYPE='R' ) WHERE hc_ID IS NULL and
 RIGHT(strtn,4) = "-LOC"
```

Could anyone say where is the mistake?

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a `right()` string function, so I am missing something.

Comment: `SUBSTR(strtn, -4, 4)` doesn't look right to me. Also, you've said you need to update, but not explained exactly what you're trying to do, and *It doesn't work* is not a meaningful problem description. It also doesn't appear that Oracle has a `right()` function. Please [edit] your question to be more clear and specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need the last 4 characters of a string. If so, then you'd

```
UPDATE add_t
   SET hc_id =
          (SELECT hc_id
             FROM hc_t
            WHERE     add_t.p_id = hc_t.facy
                  AND hco_t.TYPE = 'R')
 WHERE     hc_id IS NULL
       AND SUBSTR (strtn, -4) = '-LOC';
```

because e.g.

```
SQL> SELECT SUBSTR ('some string', -4) FROM DUAL;

SUBS
----
ring

SQL>
```

(Note also that you'd enclose strings into **single quotes** in Oracle, not double ones (as you tried with the `"-LOC"` string).